# How to call the event of one element in another element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here I have some CSS buttons over an image.  Basically what is happening now is when I click on the image, the image is zooming onto one position. Now I need the same. The CSS buttons are in a different position on the image.  Now when I click the buttons over the image, it should zoom onto that portion of the image.

I also want the same to happen onclick on another div.

Here is my code..

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#ex4').zoom({ on:'toggle',duration: 500 });
            $('.frame').css('width','100%');
                    $('#f1').zoom({ on:'toggle',duration: 500 });
    });
</script>
```

In the above code, I have a element that has `id="ex4"` and an image. When I click on the ex4 element the image zooms up.  Similarly, when I click the #f1, the image in ex4 should zoom up.  How can I do this?

Comment: where is the click event code you have used.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar its not click event. its just .zoom() funciton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Use **[trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**:

```
$("#ex4").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting the effect to happen on `#ex4` when you click the other div? If so...

Check out `.trigger()` http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Use `$('#ex4').trigger('click')` in your other function and it should simulate a click on the `#ex4` element.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use a jQuery plugin that handles the click events, which makes it possible you can use .zoom({on:'toggle',...}).
If you want to invoke the zoom when clicking on another element, you have to handle the click on those elements, for example:

```
$('#f1').click(function(evt) {
    $('#ex4').trigger('click');
});
```